# ReferenceError: guild is not defined

Tags: discord.js

I get an error when I run a command, this is my code:

```
let id = message.author.id.toString().substr(0, 4) + message.author.discriminator;
    var name = `order-${message.author}-${id}`

    guild.channels.create(name)

}
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: guild is not defined
```

I hope someone can help me! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `message.` before `guild`

```js
message.guild.channels.create(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Syntle said

```js
message.guild.channels.create(name)
```

or you can define a guild

```js
let guild = message.guild

guild.channels.create(name)
```

Comment: there is no difference between both ways

Comment: i didn't said there is a difference between these two. I'm just telling him there is more ways to do it.

Comment: I disagree, this type of suggestion could lead to untidy code.